# How to make a image data set in Python?

Tags: python, image, machine-learning

I have 26 images.  I want to make a dataset which is compatible for using principal component analysis. How can I do this in python?

Comment: If you have the images then you already have the dataset. For PCA you won't need much preprocessing. Try to read some tutorial to get the idea

Answer (score 1):

You can use skimage to read the file to a numpy array

```
from skimage import io
img = io.imread('file_path')

img.shape
Out[10]: (602, 602, 3)
```

The numpy array can you use later on in a PCA.

Comment: this is not run in pycharm. The error is (ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.)